# Issue with Option Base 1 and RemoveDuplicates VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know how to avoid in VBA a Type mismatch error message executing a code like that:

```
For i = 1 To DataRange.Columns.Count
    'MyArray(i) = i
    text1 = text1 & i & "|"
Next
text1 = Left(text1, Len(text1) - 1)
MyArray = Split(text1, "|")
DataRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=VBA.Array(MyArray)
```

I use Option Base 1 statement in module, MyArray consists of numbers from 1 to 36 and declared as Variant. When I modify this sample to

```
DataRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=VBA.Array(1,2,3,4,5 etc)
```

it works, but it is hardcoded and looks terrible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Define MyArray() as Integer

Comment: Could you please show how you fill in MyArray? Or maybe look at [this question](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/609276-vba-making-column-number-array-removeduplicates.html)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Option Base 1` has no effect whatsoever on this. FWIW you should keep your implicitly-sized arrays with the default base of `0`.  Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you fix it. At the moment your question isn't answerable.

Comment: @peakpeak thanks, it gives mistake when array is being filled

Comment: @Mormoch and that code is still not in your post.

Comment: @danieltakeshi I updated the question, thanks for your help

Comment: try this code `DataRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=VBA.Array(VBA.Array(1,2,3,4,5))` .... it will probably fail ..... it is similar to this `DataRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=VBA.Array(MyArray)`

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that VBA.Array(MyArray) is actually creating an array from MyArray.
All you want is Columns to be from MyArray.

Try

```
DataRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(MyArray)
```

The data type for Columns in Range.Removeduplicates is variant.

For Option Base 1, you will have to create a zero based array and transfer MyArray values to it.

```
ReDim zeroarray(0 To UBound(MyArray) - 1) As Variant
For i = 0 To UBound(myarray) - 1
zeroarray(i) = myarray(i + 1)
Next i
DataRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(zeroarray)
```

Comment: Sure an additional array is created, but it doesn't work with Option Base 1 statement

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Columns:= doesn't accept a Base 1 array.  You would need to convert it to a base zero array and that seems to be done by transferring the elements one by one.

Comment: you're right, I declared it as zero-based and it eventually run as I supposed.

Answer (score 1):

If `MyArray` is an array, then you should simply do

```
DataRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(MyArray)
```

The VBA [`Array function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675(v=vs.60).aspx) takes a comma separated list of values as parameter.

What you are doing is putting your array into another array, and that isn't what `RemoveDuplicates` expects.

```
? Array(1,2,3)(0)
1

? Array(Array(1,2,3))(0)
> Type mismatch

? Array(Array(1,2,3))(0)(0)
1
```

**Edit:** Props to mooseman, you actually need parentheses around MyArray. ([some hints why](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27419662/Use-RemoveDuplicates-in-VBA-with-any-size-range.html#a37067039))

```
MyArray = Array(1, 2, 3)
rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=MyArray
```

> Runtime error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument

```
MyArray = Array(1, 2, 3)
rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(MyArray)
```

> works

Comment: Andre, thanks for your help, it doesn't work when Option Base 1 is used. I would have used a zero-based array from the beginning but didn't know about it.